# How to get result by calling a routing not in app.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

In the file where I have written the request methods looks like this:
`article.js`

```
router
  .route("/")
  .all((req, res) => {
    console.log("this should happen for any call to the article route");
  })
  .get((req, res) => {
    //   returns all the data in the database
    Rest.find({}, (err, result) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log(result);
        res.send(result);
      } else {
        res.send(err);
      }
    });
  })
  .post((req, res) => {
    const articleTitle = req.body.title;
    const articleContent = req.body.content;
    const articleDate = req.body.date;
    const article = new Rest({
      title: articleTitle,
      content: articleContent,
      date: articleDate,
    });
    article
      .save()
      .then((result) => {
        res.send(result);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        res.send(err);
      });
  })
  .delete((req, res) => {
    Rest.deleteMany({}, (err, result) => {
      if (!err) {
        res.send(result);
      } else {
        res.send(err);
      }
    });
  });

module.exports = router;
```

and I have and `app.js`

```
const article = require("./article");
app.use('/articles', article);
```

When I make a call to url it just loads and I get no response.
At first I was just writing it http verb on it own. But it was making my `app.js` have a lot of code so I decided to move all this logic to its own file `article.js` and use `router.route()` to chain the http verbs together to make the code look cleaner. But doing that I encounter the error when I get no result and it just loads forever.
Am I doing something wrong?
Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The solution was to add `next()` to `.all()` method. Because I was passing next, I think the http request was just stuck at that point waiting.
So the new code should be

```
router
.route('/')
.all((req, res, next)) => {
    // logic
    next();
})
```

and the rest of the code follows.